# Can't load Nexus 7 USB driver for Android debugging on WinXP

Tags: android

I am very new to Android development.

I ran the tutorial for creating the *Hello, world* app and ran it successfully on the Android emulator.  Now I want to try it on a Nexus 7 tablet and can't get the required USB driver to load on this WinXP system.  Things I have done:

Ran the SDK Manager to install the Google USB driver on my machine.  The directory <sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver containing a .inf file and a bunch of other stuff showed up as expected.

On the tablet, enabled debugging mode.  It now shows *USB debugging* checked in the *Developer options* menu.

Plugged in the tablet to the USB.  Windows popped up the *found new hardware* dialog.

Following the [directions from Google](https://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html), eventually gave it the path to the driver in <sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver.

Windows then says that it can't install the device.  I have tried rebooting the PC, turning the tablet off and on, turning off USB debugging in the tablet and then on again, but nothing has worked.

How do I get the driver loaded so that I can debug Android apps on the tablet?

### Added:

Here is the screen shot of trying to tell Windows where the driver is:

[image]

And here is the response after clicking NEXT above:

[image]

Something flashes up very briefly before this, but it's too fast to see what it's saying.

### The Solution

I got things working thanks to [Andrew Q](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844992/andrew-q), but my details were a little different from his so I am documenting them here in case someone else bumps into this with a setup more like mine.

The main thing that made the difference is changing the tablet's USB behavior from a mass storage device to a camera.  On Andrew's device this setting is apparently in the normal Settings menu you can get to when swiping down in the top right corner.  In my case Settings > Storage only displays some statistics with no (apparent) options.  However, when the device is connected to the USB in debug mode, there is a little icon in the top left corner that is four vertical lines.  Swiping that down shows you whether the device is connected as a media device (MTP) or a camera (PTP), and allows you to select either.  Mine was MTP by default, and switching to PTP did the trick.

Once the device was in PTP mode, WinXP was able to load the Google driver without problem.  I didn't have to deliberately uninstall and manually install the driver.  The "Found New Hardware Wizard" shown above actually worked instead of resulting in "Cannot Install this Hardware".

Once that was done everything worked as expected.  Eclipse could see the tablet and allowed me to select it as a target after Run > Run.

Comment: Can you provide details from the Windows failure screen/dialog?

Comment: @Larry: I have added screen shots to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem on Windows 7 and I think this may help you. Sometimes the USB driver available in the SDK location does not link correctly using the "Found New Hardware" program on Windows XP. Here's what you can try:

1. First plug in your Nexus 7. Since USB debugging is enabled that shouldn't be a problem. You may, however, need to head to Settings --> Storage --> Under the menu button in the top right-hand corner tap "USB computer connection" --> Check camera. Do this on your N7 of course.
2. Now head onto your PC and open your device manager (Click [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/snap_dev_mgr.mspx?mfr=true) for help on that). Uninstall anything that resembles your Nexus 7. Now it should show up as an unknown device. Right click on it --> Select "Update Driver Software" --> It will ask you to locate the driver...point it to the one in the SDK location.
3. If that's successful, go into your IDE (Eclipse ADT or Android Studio) and run your application.

I hope this helps!

Andrew

Comment: Thanks, your help got it working.  My details were a little different, so I documented them in the question in case others have a setup more like mine than yours.  Now, why coudn't Google mention this little MTP versus PTP issue...?